# Does $K(x)=E(x)$ imply $K=E$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let us suppose we have two fields $K$ and $E$ and $K\subseteq E$. Is it true that $K(x)=E(x)$ implies $K=E$? I know it seems sort of obvious, but I don't know if it is actually true. It is for a step in something I'm trying to prove for my homework.

Comment: I see it now, @Omnomnomnom Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is negative, take $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $E=\mathbb{Q}(x^2)$. Then obviously $K(x)=E(x)$ but $K\neq E$.

Comment: @user26857 the only reason I provided an answer was that someone has given a false answer above.

Comment: @user26857 I have accidentally seen this question, as the false answer provided in the above comment may misguide the person who has asked the question, I intervened.

Comment: @user26857 by the way I am unregistered user and not having enough reputation to comment.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb Q(x^2)$ is not a **field**

Comment: The OP might be assuming implicitly that $x$ is transcendenal over both $E$ and $K$. @Omnomnomnom Yes it is.

Comment: @whacka what is the multiplicative inverse of $x^2$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $x^{-2}$

Comment: @whacka I see what you mean now